# normal distribution of cracks in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

From the scripts below, the cracks were distributed randomly in the rock formation with dimensions of 200x200. The crack density is estimated from the scripts and the histograms of crack density and final crack lengths are plotted. My task is to distribute the cracks not randomly but probabilistically with normal distribution. I have edit the rand code in matlab to (randn which normally distributes the random numbers). Since in matlab normal distribution using positive and negative integers, the negative integers were eliminated with abs code which uses only absolute integers via converting negative integers to positive since I cannot have negative cracks.

```
t = 0.2 + 0.1.*randn(L,L);
r = abs(t);
z = r<porosity;
```

The 0.2 and 0.1 are the mean and standard deviation which I made up to have bell shape distribution. For normal distribution, the graph should be bell shaped but from the edited scripts I am getting half of the bell shape and it is not evenly distributed as it normally distributes. Is there any ways of getting normal distribution with bell shape? 
Thanks in advance for your help!
Here is the script:

```
%Finding Crack Density for selected P, N times
global X_Tips Y_Tips
Cycles = 1000;
Crack_Density_Values = zeros(1,Cycles);
%In the furutre porosite will be taken from a calcualted range for some
%dimension L 
critical_crack_Length = 12;
L = 200;
porosity = 0.041;

 %Applying Temperature Gradient
v = 0:1:L;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(v);
Z =  10000 + (X.^2 + Y.^2);
[px,py] = gradient(Z,1);
for i10 = 1:Cycles
    r = rand(L,L);
    z = r<porosity;
    %Assigns a unique ID to each individual void. num tells us how many void
    %exist.
    [lw, num] = bwlabel(z,8);
    %Before crack propagation 
    img = label2rgb(lw);
%Go through each crack and propagate until length of one crack == ccl
%For this exmaple, assume critical crack length = 12 sqaures 
    Number_of_cracks = num;
    %Find size of each crack first, gives me amount of increments needed for
    %one crack to reach critical crack length
    critical_crack_length = 12; %Assumed for this example. 
    Crack_Lengths = zeros(1,num); 
    for i = 1:Number_of_cracks
        id = i;
        %finding coordinates of crack
        [r,c] = find(lw==id);
        rc = [r c]; %[x,y]
        rc_size = size(rc);
        Crack_Length = max(rc_size);
        Crack_Lengths(i) = Crack_Length;
    end 
    %Finding minium increment needed to reach CCL
    max_crack_length = max(Crack_Lengths);
    Increments = critical_crack_length - max_crack_length;
    %I've now got my crack increment length
    %now we to calculate crack density after failure. 
    %Getting Half Crack Lengths (Crack_Lengths does not update so I can just go
    %through that and add the increment/
    Final_Crack_Lengths = Crack_Lengths + Increments;
    %Half Crack Lengths
    Half_Crack_Length = Final_Crack_Lengths ./ 2;
    Volume = L*L*1; %unit thickness
    Crack_Density = (sum((Half_Crack_Length.^3)))/ Volume;
    Crack_Density_Values(i10) = Crack_Density;
end
%Hisogram for data 
figure(1)
plot(Crack_Density_Values,'*')
figure(2)
nbins = 5
hist(Final_Crack_Lengths, nbins)
```